# Arc<Mutex<T>> inside closure: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to share an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` with a closure. I get the error that `closure is` FnOnce`because it moves the variable`shared_wake_deque_ `out of its environment`:

```
use core::task::{Context, Poll, Waker};
use hyper::client::connect::{Connection, Connected};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub type OnPollRead = Arc<dyn Fn(&mut Context<'_>, &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> + Send + Sync>;
pub type OnPollWrite = Arc<dyn Fn(&mut Context<'_>, &[u8]) -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>> + Send + Sync>;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct CustomTransporter {
    on_poll_read: Option<OnPollRead>,
    on_poll_write: Option<OnPollWrite>,
}

pub struct OVPNClient {
}

impl OVPNClient {
    pub fn send(&self, buffer: &[u8]) {
        
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for OVPNClient {}


unsafe impl Send for CustomTransporter {}

impl CustomTransporter {
    pub fn new(on_poll_read: Option<OnPollRead>, on_poll_write: Option<OnPollWrite>) -> CustomTransporter {
        CustomTransporter{
            on_poll_read: on_poll_read,
            on_poll_write: on_poll_write
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
    let openvpn_client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(OVPNClient{}));

    let shared_wake_deque = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::<Waker>::new()));
    
    let shared_wake_deque_ = shared_wake_deque.clone();
    let on_poll_read = Arc::new(|context: &mut Context, buffer: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf| -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        let shared_wake_deque__ = shared_wake_deque_;
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    });

    let on_poll_write = Arc::new(|context: &mut Context, buffer: &[u8]| -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>>{
        openvpn_client.lock().unwrap().send(buffer);
        Poll::Ready(Ok(0))
    });

    let connector = CustomTransporter::new(Some(on_poll_read), Some(on_poll_write));
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:44:33
   |
44 |     let on_poll_read = Arc::new(|context: &mut Context, buffer: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf| -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
45 |         let shared_wake_deque__ = shared_wake_deque_;
   |                                   ------------------ closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `shared_wake_deque_` out of its environment
...
54 |     let connector = CustomTransporter::new(Some(on_poll_read), Some(on_poll_write));
   |                                                 ------------ the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

I get that moving can only occur one time. I didn't even made the closure `move`. As you see, I'm trying to use a clone of the `Arc<Mutex<T>>` so I'm not exactly moving it. You can see that I tried cloning so I move a variable that is used just on this closure and never anymore, but it didn't work.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d996163f5d2a6e9322af9a7472581ce6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have

```
let shared_wake_deque__ = shared_wake_deque_;
```

as a simple assignment, it is no different from

```
let foo = vec![];
let foo2 = foo;
```

where running code transfers ownership of the vec from `foo` to `foo2`.  Because you have this in a lambda, running the explicitly transfers ownership of the `shared_wake_deque_` value to `shared_wake_deque__`, meaning that `shared_wake_deque_` can't be used any more. For that to be possible, it is required that `on_poll_read` can only run a single time, because otherwise multiple things would be trying to own the same object (both `on_poll_read`, since it would need to own it in order to use in some future call, and the `shared_wake_deque__` from any previous call would also still have to own it). Since that would be a violation of Rust's safety guarantees because something can only be owned by one thing, you are getting this error.

Most likely, what you want is to us a reference, e.g.

```
let shared_wake_deque__ = &shared_wake_deque_;
```

By using a reference to `shared_wake_deque_`, the closure is allowed to run multiple times and give out multiple shared references. With only that alone however, you'll then get

```
error[E0597]: `shared_wake_deque_` does not live long enough
```

because you're trying to reference a variable that is declared outside the closure, and the closure could run after `shared_wake_deque_` was dropped. To solve *that*, you need the closure to take ownership of `shared_wake_deque_`, which is accomplished by using the `move` keyword, e.g.

```
let on_poll_read = Arc::new(move |context: &mut Context, buffer: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf| -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
    let shared_wake_deque__ = &shared_wake_deque_;
```

then the same problem also arises for `on_poll_write` so that needs to be `move` too:

```
let on_poll_write = Arc::new(move |context: &mut Context, buffer: &[u8]| -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>>{
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d764f13df581f970e95d7d08e869dffd))